# Using User Defined Classes

Tags: swift

I am trying to instantiate a user-defined object called Rock. With this code, "contains" is a variable of type Item, and both Rock and Bug are sub classes of Item. The code generates errors when I try to instantiate Rock, but not Bug. Is this not how you instantiate a class? It says "cannot assign value of type Rock.Type to type 'item.'

Also, I was wondering how I would write the code for asking the object "contains" what class of object it contains. Is there a function for that?

```
    for r in 0...map.MAXROWS{
        for c in 0...map.MAXCOLUMNS{
            if (r < 3) || (r > (MAXROWS - 3)){
                self.contains = Rock
            }else if (c < 3) || (c > (MAXCOLUMNS - 3)){
                self.contains = Rock
            }else if (r == 3) && (c == 100){
                self.contains = Bug(index: 1, map: map)
            }else if (arc4random() * 100 == 1){
                self.contains = Bug(index: current, map: map)
                current = current + 1
            }else if (arc4random() * 8) == 1{
                self.contains = Rock
            }
        }
    }


import Cocoa

class Bug: Item {
    var male = true
    var direction = 1
    var appearance = 1
    var positionRow = 0
    var positionColumn = 0

    // Direction:
    // 1 = Up
    // 2 = Right
    // 3 = Down
    // 4 = Left

    init(index: Int, map: Map){
        super.init()
        map.initializeBugs(index: index, current: self)
        if (index == 1){
            self.direction = 3
            self.positionRow = 3
            self.positionColumn = 100
        }else{
            self.direction = (Int(arc4random() * 4)) + 1
        }
        Birth(index: index)
    }

    func Birth(index: Int){
        if (arc4random() * 8) == 1{
            self.male = false
        }else{
            self.male = true
            if (arc4random() * 2) == 1{
                self.appearance = 1
            }else{
                self.appearance = 2
            }
        }
    }

    func DisplayBug() -> Int{
        if self.male == false{
            return self.direction
        }else{
            if self.appearance == 1{
                switch self.direction{
                case 1:
                    return 5
                case 2:
                    return 6
                case 3:
                    return 7
                case 4:
                    return 8
                default:
                    return 0
                }
            }else if self.appearance == 2{
                switch self.direction{
                case 1:
                    return 9
                case 2:
                    return 10
                case 3:
                    return 11
                case 4:
                    return 12
                default:
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func WhereAreYouRow() -> Int{
        return self.positionRow
    }

    func WhereAreYouColumn() -> Int{
        return self.positionColumn
    }

    func AreYouBug() -> Bool{
        return true
    }

    func InstantiateBug{

    }
}



import Cocoa

class Rock: Item {

    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    func AreYouRock() -> Bool{
        return true
    }
```

Comment: You probably mean `self.contains = Rock()`  to assign an *instance* of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: `trying to instantiate a user-defined object called Rock` *instantiate an object/create an instance of a class called Rock*

Comment: Please check how to accept an answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/469186

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a constructor to instantiate classes like: `Rock()` or `Bug()`

When calling just `Rock` or `Bug`, without the `()` you're referencing the class, what you wanna do is create an object and therefore you need `()`

---

In shorter words:

**Classes**: `Rock`, `Bug`

**Objects**: `Rock()`, `Bug()`

so in your code, you want to assign `self.contains = Object` which means:

`self.contains = Rock()` or `self.contains = Bug()`

Comment: I did this and this initially got rid of the error. However, I closed Xcode and opened it again and the error message is back.

Comment: that doesn't make sense, make sure you saved it, what is the new error?

Comment: The error disappeared again. It was a false alarm. I am not very familiar with Xcode.